# Hardware menu popup issue with Appcompat

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, popup, android-appcompat

I implemented in my application the (not so) new Appcompat theme with DarkActionBar. Everything works fine, except the popup from hardware menu button (or long press the recent button), that is rendered with white text.

Popup result:

Toolbar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/huWpm.png

Hard menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5fmL.png

I solved an old issue with the popup from Action Mode, adding the actionBarPopupTheme attribute in the app theme. After this, the Hardware Menu popup is also getting the background from actionBarPopupTheme (Ok, we want! Before it was black), but not the textcolor.

The code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>

    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
</style>

<style name="Toolbar" parent="MatchWidth">
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

What is the right way to theme this?

Comment: Have you got any solution? Struggling with similar issue!!